# Need to retrieve URL param along with passing an object with app,put

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I currently have the following fetch I need to use where it is a PUT with data being sent in the body of JSON.    However, I also need the ID in the URL.

```
  async addExercise(data) {
    const id = location.search.split("=")[1];
    const res = await fetch("/api/workouts/" + id, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
 
    const json = await res.json();

    return json;
  }
```

And my route on the backend needs not only the body object, but also the :id param.

```
app.put("/api/workouts/:id", ({body}, res) => {

  db.Exercise.create(body)
    .then(({ _id }) => db.WorkoutPlan.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $push: { exercises: _id } }, { new: true }))
    .then(dbUser => {
      console.log(dbUser);
      res.json(dbUser);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Currently, the code works to add the exercise to a workoutPlan.    But it is always adding to the first workoutplan.    Therefore I need the :id param, but not sure how to retrieve that.    I have tried body.params.id and various other forms all to no avail.    If I use (body, res) then I can get the id with body.params.id but I then don't have the other fields being passed in such as name, distance, duration.

I'm at a loss and looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the backend route that your fetch is making an api call to? It should be

```
const express=  require("express");

const router = express.Router()
router.put("/api/workouts/:id", function(req, res){
  //retrieve the id with
req.params.id
//to get the data
req.body

})
module.exports=router
```

You would import this file to the  main file that runs your server and use with app.use

```
const routes= require("path to route file")
app.use(routes);
```

Comment: sorry, my markup caused the first line not to show.    I fixed above.   Not sure this totally answers what I need to do.  I have exercise data from form that is being pushed to backend in "data" that I need to save to a workoutplan ID.    that's why the ID was a param from URL.    I just can't seem to utilize both types of data on back end.   The ID being passed in needs to be used after the Exercise.create is called such that db.WorkoutPlan.findOneAndUpdate stores Exercise _id to correct workoutplan ID.

Comment: The req.params.id gets the id from the url. req.body gets the data you are pushing. I made a small edit to the question